# Magento 2.3 After migration how to sync images from Magento 1.9 server?

Tags: magento2.3.3, delta-migration

How to sync images to Magento 2.3.3 from Magento 1.9.2.3 live server.

After successfully migrated Magento 2.3.3 from Magento 1.9.2.3 how to sync images from live Magento 1.9.2.3 server?

Comment: I see this an update from our previous discussion, nice progress!  
Did you run `bin/magento migrate:delta` afterwards to create **m2_cl** tables inside the source M1 Database?

You need to copy them from the live server locally via zip/tar contents as far as I know.  M2 migration tool only handles most of the database functions.

Comment: you need to manually upload `media/catalog` folder at `pub/media/catalog`. refer : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-manually.html

Comment: After migration ssl error : https://snipboard.io/fwTNaI.jpg  @Pawan , CvRChameleon

Comment: it seems, magento 1 have SSL but migrated server does not have SSL enabled.

Comment: `UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml'` and
`UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/use_in_frontend'`

Comment: try above commands

Answer (score 0):

You can easily migrate manually images from live Magento 1.9.2.3 server, following this Magento document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-manually.html